# Is there any way to secure api call in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

Whenever you call api from angularjs,its shows basic details of api on browser console like (endpoints,parameters,response), so is there any way to hide or secure this details? Or how to encrypt my parameters and responses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so is there any way to hide or secure this details?
>
> endpoints

Nope. The client must be able to use them. If your JS can see them, so can the user.

> parameters, response

Nope. Theoretically, you could encrypt them, but this is ultimately a meaningless activity, as the client must possess the keys needed to decrypt everything, and the user will have them too.

Comment: How can i encrypt that?

Comment: @MayurShah: 1. Out of scope here. 2. Did you not read the answer? The encryption would be meaningless, as it will be quite easy to undo it.

Comment: @2 yes i ready the ans carefully,but i want to know how its possible.

Comment: @MayurShah: well, in this case, google up on symmetric encryption, for example. But I warn you again, it's not worth the effort.

Comment: Not getting you exactly. I know there are may methods are available for encryption.

Comment: @MayurShah: yes, so you can read their documentation and learn how to implement them, right?

Comment: @MayurShah: I was just suggesting that, in my opinion, one type of encryption (symmetric crypto) is more suitable for this.

Comment: @segio Tulentsev: yeah,but i want to know angular or any plugins or any way can provide this kind of features? That encrypt your data or api requests and responses?

Comment: @MayurShah: I don't know of such things. Most likely, you'll have to do everything yourself.